# reconnect automatically when client gets back the lost connection in JW Player

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I want the client to automatically connect to the server when the connection is back and the video should start playing where it stopped before. Is it possible..?

Till now i tried making connection again after 3 seconds and video starts from first.

```
jwplayer().onBuffer(function()
{
    theTimeout = setTimeout(function()
    {
       window.location = window.location.href;
    },3000);
});
```

But i want the video to start from where it stopped playing before..
can anyone help me regarding this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message

```
jwplayer().onBuffer(function(){
theTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
jwplayer().load({file:"http://example.com/errorfile.mp4",image:"http://example.com/errorfile.jpg"});
jwplayer().play();
},5000);
});
```

Edit, try this:

```
jwplayer().onBuffer(function(){
var thePosition = jwplayer().getPosition();
theTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
jwplayer().load({file:"http://example.com/errorfile.mp4",image:"http://example.com/errorfile.jpg"});
jwplayer().seek(thePosition );
},5000);
});
```

Comment: Sir, But i want the same video to play again and from the position the connection was lost previously. Just like handling handover from one network to another.

Comment: Is it a VOD file or a live stream?

Comment: but onBuffer() function is not working fine...
This function is starting when the video is starting and video is ending after the timeout mentioned in the function..|
But i want the video to be loaded again when connection is lost and retained.
can you help in clearing my doubt..?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. My code above will make the player see if it takes too long to buffer, captures the current seek time, and then re-loads the file and then re-seeks to that time. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: here in your code, you are using onBuffer(), which reloads the page after the time(which is measured from  starting of video), which is mentioned in the setTimeout() function. Here(in your code) it is 5 seconds.
 But what i want to do is, if in video when it stops buffering then the timeout function should trigger and do the remaining things as seeking the position where it stopped before.
So, im saying using onBuffer is not ideal solution in my case since it measures time from very starting point of video.
So any other function that might help the case, it should trigger once the buffer stops

Comment: I am not re-loading the page. I am checking if the player times out via buffering, then re loading the player. The page does not reload here.

Comment: sir, How to make this particular change in the player code.? Till now Im doing script on the webpage, but can we put this code in player source code which i got from Github. If we can, which file i should be modifying.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This code is not meant to go into the player source. It is meant to go on the webpage only.

Comment: No supported to do it in that way.